# Enable mobile web app to open a link in user mobile default browser instead of opening inside the app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, vue.js

I've created a mobile web app for Android and iOS. I've installed the apk and ipa in my test phones.

However, I'm having a problem when I'm trying to open an external link that requires to open in user default browser(Safari, Chrome)

I've tried the following:

1. target="_blank"
2. window.open('url','_blank');

But the links are just opening inside the Web App.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of android web view is to open links using the default browser.

If you have put **myWebView.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient);** in your code then remove it as using this will open links inside application only